# discord bot ref (C#)

Tags: c#, discord, ref

I kind of suck att everything C# but what I am trying to do is that you will write 
"b!roll [number]" and it will generate a random number from 0 to [number]. But I don't understand how to use the number you input at the command in other parts so that I can use "number" as it says in my code in other parts like a var.

```
     commands.CreateCommand("!random")
            .Parameter("number", ParameterType.Required)
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                Random random = new Random();

                int randomNumber = random.Next(0, number);

                await e.Channel.SendMessage(":game_die: You rolled your **" + number "** sided die and got the number **" + randomNumber + "**!");
            });
```

This is probably really simple but I can't seem to understand but I would love if someone helped so that I can understand C# better.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the parameter with `e.GetArg(parameterName)`:

```
int number;
if (!int.TryParse(e.GetArg("number"), out number)
{
    // handle error
}

// rest of your logics...
```